# How to rotate rounded ImageView

Tags: android, rotation, rounded-corners, rotatetransform

I have a problem when i rotated `ImageView`:

[image: NOW]

But i want that picture to be like this after i made this `ImageView` to be rounded first:

[image: how it should be]

So, how can i do that? This is my xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#f1f1f1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_propotionalimageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bg_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_vouchers_rounded_shadow"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_background" />

     </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

Comment: Please share your rotation code. It seems like you need to change the image size programatically.

Comment: I rotated this imageview by xml code, I added android:rotation="90" on ImageView

Comment: Do you have two xml files? It's hard to understand... try to change layout_width and layout_height to "match_parent".

Comment: try to change `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to something like `fill` or `scale`